# Java casting wildcard to template type

Tags: java, generics

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import java.util.Collection;

public class GenericsTest {

    private final Multimap<String, Box<?>> boxMultimap;

    public GenericsTest(Multimap<String, Box<?>> boxMultimap) {
        this.boxMultimap = boxMultimap;
    }

    public <T> Collection<Box<T>> get(final String boxType) {
        final Collection<Box<T>> boxes = boxMultimap.get(boxType);

        return boxes;
    }
}
```

Box:

```
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

How would I cast `boxMultimap.get(boxType);` to type `<T>` for this specific `get` example method. The above fails to retrieve from the multimap.

The following works just fine:

```
public class GenericsTest {

    private final Multimap<String, Box> boxMultimap;

    public GenericsTest(Multimap<String, Box> boxMultimap) {
        this.boxMultimap = boxMultimap;
    }

    public <T> Collection<Box<T>> get(final String boxType) {
        final Collection boxes = boxMultimap.get(boxType);

        return boxes;
    }
}
```

But I wanted to be explicit on the local boxes collection variable (`final Collection<Box<T>> boxes = boxMultimap.get(boxType);`).

Comment: maybe making the class an actual generic? because your problem is that you are also not declaring the generic type of `Box` in the constructor, that will cause a warning I supposes

Comment: Do you happen to know what the element types are for a given `boxType`?  You're going to need to do an unsafe cast at some point.

Comment: I've tried different variations of making Box a generic in the constructor. Even using a wildcard (?) still causing problems attempting to convert from ? to T